# Make charts dynamically in WFA

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I need to create few charts in WFA. I have few `double[]` arrays, depending how many data sets I will load, so number of charts will change.

What is the easiest way to make it dynamically? Is it possible to use controls or I have to program my own chart?

For example I tried this, but it's not showing anything in a form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();
    chart.Series.Add("C4.5");
    chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
    chart.ChartAreas[0].Visible = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto= true;
    chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;


    chart.Visible = true;
    double[] a = new double[]
    {
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1
    };
    chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(a);
}
```

Comment: You didn't add the Chart to your form, did you? (maybe `chart.Parent = this`)

Comment: chart.Parent= this  works, thanks